# Spring boot 2.3.3.RELEASE classpath unknown warninng

Tags: spring-boot

i am getting this warning when i am starting my spring boot application, i check java_home settinngs which is valid. What might cause this warning do you have any ideas?
I am using Intellij Idea as my Ide.
Thanks,

**ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: unknown**

Comment: Are you using some IDE?  Can you also add details about it in the question?

Answer (score 1):

The classpath is logged at debug level rather than a warning. It's logged as `unknown` when the thread context class loader (TCCL) isn't a `URLClassLoader`:

```java
private String getClasspath() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
        return Arrays.toString(((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs());
    }
    return "unknown";
}
```

If you're running your app in your IDE on Java 9 or later the TCCL will not be a `URLClassLoader`. As a result, the classpath will be logged as `unknown`. It doesn't not mean that there is a problem with your application and you can safely ignore it. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/23138) so that we can review the usefulness of `ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener`.

Comment: Thank you Andy, i appreciate your answer!